# "user defined type not defined" error with no help from debugger

Tags: sql, vba, excel, db2

I'm trying to create a macro to pull some data from a database. However when trying to run the following code I get a "Compile error: User-defined type not defined" error message. The debugger just highlights the Sub line so I have no idea where the offender is.

```
Sub PCA_test()
'
' PCA_test Macro
'

'
'Declare variables'
Set objAbConn = New ADODB.Connection
Set objAbRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQLProductSales As String

'Open Connection'
objAbConn.ConnectionString = "DSN=AWPROD;UID=abc;PWD=123;MODE=SHARE;DBALIAS=AWPROD;TXNISOLATION=1;"
objAbConn.Open

'Set and Excecute SQL Command'
strSQLProductSales = "SELECT CELL_CODE, CONTROL_TREATMENT_FLAG, COUNT(DISTINCT A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)AS CUSTS_MAILED," & _
"COUNT(DISTINCT C.ACCOUNT_NUMBER)AS CUSTS_REDEEMED," & _
"SUM(TXNS) AS TXNS, SUM(SALES) AS SALES, SUM(UNITS) AS UNITS, SUM(ONLINE_SALES) AS ONLINE_SALES" & _
"FROM    (SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, CAMPAIGN_CODE, CELL_CODE, CONTROL_TREATMENT_FLAG" & _
"FROM CONTACT" & _
"WHERE CAMPAIGN_CODE = 'C000006816') A" & _
"LEFT JOIN" & _
"(SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, COUNT(DISTINCT EPOS_TRANSACTION_KEY) AS TXNS," & _
"SUM(SALES_AT_TISP) AS SALES, SUM(SALES_UNITS) AS UNITS," & _
"SUM(CASE WHEN STORE_NUMBER = 4910 THEN SALES_AT_TISP ELSE 0 END) AS ONLINE_SALES" & _
"FROM TRANSACTIONS AA" & _
"INNER JOIN ITEMS BB" & _
"ON AA.ITEM_CODE = BB.ITEM_CODE" & _
"WHERE TILL_TRANSACTION_DATE BETWEEN '2015-06-22' AND '2015-07-20'" & _
"AND AA.ITEM_CODE IN (0000, 1111, 2222)" & _
"GROUP BY ACCOUNT_NUMBER) C" & _
"ON C.ACCOUNT_NUMBER =A.ACCOUNT_NUMBER" & _
"GROUP BY CELL_CODE, CONTROL_TREATMENT_FLAG" & _
"ORDER BY CELL_CODE;"

'Open Recordset'
Set objAbRecordset.ActiveConnection = objAbConn
objAbRecordset.Open strSQLProductSales

'Copy Data to Excel'
Sheet("ProductSales").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset (objAbRecordset)


End Sub
```

I believe I have the right references ticked. That's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: you haven't set `objAbConn` and `objAbRecordset` with the `Dim` keyword

Comment: Minimize the problem, i.e. remove one piece, try to execute, does it work? If not you've find the problem part, otherwise remove something else etc.

Comment: In addition check the VBA library references, maybe someone is missing.

Comment: as to what psychicebola said look here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257819

Comment: Once you fix the problems above, you'll get the syntax error for the query -- make sure you put spaces where they are required.

Answer (score 1):

I pasted your code into the vba editor and the line being highlighted is:

```
Set objAbConn = New ADODB.Connection
```

This needs to be declared differently:

```
Dim objAbConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim objAbRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset
```

Remember to close the connection and recordset when done:

```
objAbRecordset.Close
objAbConn.Close
```

Also, I included the reference to "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library"

Good luck.